# make config yaml more readable for nested list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have this sample YAML:

```
people:
      name: abc
      address: '55 Oxford Street, San Jose 95134. CA'
      occupation: 'Travel Blogger'
      Hobby: 'Travelling'
      additional_interests: []
      other_info: [['gender', 'male'], ['no_of_cars', 'three'],
             ['hair_color', 'black'], ['eye_color', 'brown']]
```

Which I want to render it in such a way that the output yaml should be:

```
people:
      name: abc
      address: '55 Oxford Street, San Jose 95134. CA'
      occupation: 'Travel Blogger'
      Hobby: 'Travelling'
      additional_interests: []
      other_info: [
          ['gender', 'male'], 
          ['no_of_cars', 'three'],
          ['hair_color', 'black'], 
          ['eye_color', 'brown']
      ]
```

I am using following code:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML as Ruamel
from pathlib import Path
yaml = Ruamel(typ='rt')
config_file = Path('/Users/test_config.yaml')
configs = yaml.load(config_file.read_text())
component_file="xyz.txt"
with open(component_file, 'w') as component:
    for key, value in configs.items():
        yaml.default_flow_style=None
        yaml.dump({key: value}, component)
```

Idea here is to convert existing YAML files into more human readable format. Any pointers how can I achieve the format I am looking for - for nested list in YAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If used, you only need to set `yaml.default_flow_style` once. but in
round-trip mode this only affects newly created `dict`s and `list`s. All loaded data structure have their block/flow style explicitly set and preserved, and are not affected by `.default_flow_style`.
It is also almost always a bad idea to dump a YAML document in increments to a file, you can easily create invalid/unloadable YAML documents that way.

As documented, `ruamel.yaml` explicitly tries to preserve **block** style,
and conversely (mostly) normalizes flow-style.
A good test to see if you can achieve what you want as output is by round-tripping the intended YAML format
to see if `ruamel.yaml` can re-generate your formatting (and if it does inspect the nodes for
their  special attributes if you want to create them from scratch).

In your case you'll notice that `ruamel.yaml` doesn't specifically handle these nested flow-style lists
and normalizes them to the, unwanted, sample format.

If there had been comments in between the elements of the nested sequence, you'd noticed that
`ruamel.yaml` currently cannot properly deal with these. They don't get lost, but they
get inserted into a line of their own, which is a good indication that trying to insert empty
comments between the elements of the outer sequence will result in extra newlines as well.

My primary recommendation is to not nest flow style sequences.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
people:
      name: abc
      address: '55 Oxford Street, San Jose 95134. CA'
      occupation: 'Travel Blogger'
      Hobby: 'Travelling'
      additional_interests: []
      other_info: [['gender', 'male'], ['no_of_cars', 'three'],
             ['hair_color', 'black'], ['eye_color', 'brown']]
"""

def no_nested_flow_style_seq(d):
    done = False
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            no_nested_flow_style_seq(v)  # you can have sequences as keys in YAML, but it is rare
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for elem in d:
            if not done and isinstance(elem, list):
                done = True
                d.fa.set_block_style()
            no_nested_flow_style_seq(elem)


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
no_nested_flow_style_seq(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
people:
  name: abc
  address: 55 Oxford Street, San Jose 95134. CA
  occupation: Travel Blogger
  Hobby: Travelling
  additional_interests: []
  other_info:
  - [gender, male]
  - [no_of_cars, three]
  - [hair_color, black]
  - [eye_color, brown]
```

To get the indent size of 6 spaces for the (block-style) mapping
sequences, as in your sample output, you can
set `yaml.indent(mapping=6, sequence=6, offset=4)` before dumping.
However, with regards to. human readability, there is an article "Program indentation
and comprehensibility" (1983, by Miara, Musselman, Navarro and Shneiderman
(the latter of Nassi-Shneiderman diagram fame)
in Communications of the ACM), that shows that comprehensibility for programming languages
is optimal for indents of 2-4 spaces, and decreases for higher values.
I don't know about specific research for human-readable data formats, and such
things are highly dependent on what you are used to, and therefore difficult to
judge out of personal experience, but
I recommend not to use such large indents for YAML.

The above loads to the same data structure as both of your YAML samples (for all
normal processing, the formatting information is of course stored somewhere, but certainly
other programs, not using ruamel.yaml in roundtrip mode see no difference)..
You can set `yaml.preserve_quotes = True`, but IMO you would need to
deal with the inconsistencies of quoting (`abc` vs `'Travelling'`) if humans
are to look at these files. Setting that also loads the same data structure.

If the data format can be changed, you should consider changing the value for
`other_info` to a list of dicts:

```
  - gender: male
  - no_of_cars: three
  - hair_color: black
  - eye_color: brown
```

or to a list of tagged scalars, that would allow you to load them into their fitting class instances
(and e.g. check for allowed scalar value):

```
  - !Gender male
  - !No_Of_Cars three
  - !Hair_Color black
  - !Eye_Color brown
```